# What would be a good algorithm to show recommended items to users in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

On shopping sites users are given recommendations based on their purchasing habits, on dating sites users are recommended members based on their personality tests and/or locations.

I have a need to display to my site's user's other members who are near them so they can make new friends etc.

What would be a good way to go about this?

In order to avoid displaying the same old people over and over I was thinking of doing something like this,

at first displaying other members who are in the same zip code as the user. And having a "displayed" flag in the database which would be a timestamp that's updated each time a member is recommended.

Before displaying I can check to see if the displayed timestamp is at least a week old, if so then I can show them, otherwise I will venture further and further and display other members who are in the same city, state, country, etc.

This seems a bit complicated and will require a lot of database checks and processing time in general. So I was wondering, if there is an easier way. Are there any established way to do these sorts of recommended lists functionality?

Comment: I would run a million dollar competition for people to come up with good ideas: http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/09/21/netflix-awards-1-million-prize-and-starts-a-new-contest/

Comment: why don't you filter the records on required conditions and sort them as random order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node, Graph, and Recommendation Databases are designed explicitly for this task.

http://easyrec.org/

http://neo4j.org/

http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/suggest/overview

http://mahout.apache.org/

I would recommend not attempting to re-implement this especially with a *Relational Database*.  Speaking from experience when I had a client that wanted Yelp-Like features using only PHP and MySQL - it is like shoving a square peg in a round hole.